# Merge of tags `info-visualisation` and `info-visualization` into ìnfoviz`

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Having insufficient privileges within the tags [info-visualisation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/info-visualisation) and [info-visualization](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/info-visualization), I am not able to suggest synonyms. However, if we keep those tags separately it will take even longer before anyone will be able to edit. I suggest adding the two as synonyms for [infoviz](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infoviz).

How to do this? Or who to ask?

<sub>(Pardon me for asking here on Meta. I was, however, not able to find any other place to raise the issue, and it certainly does not belong on the Main site.)</sub>

Comment: +1 for merging.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up. This is the right place to do so. :-)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us

Answer (score 2):

Let's go with info-visualisation, since that's the more popular spelling by far. I started a tag synonym for the other spelling. **It needs four up votes to become official.**

https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/info-visualisation/synonyms

Comment: I would upvote but I can't yet. I need to get an answer score for that tag first.

Comment: @Charles Oh well, since there are so few tags, it would probably be more efficient to just retag the ones spelled with a 'z'. :-)

Comment: I'll go do that for now. Once we can get it upvoted, the synonym will still be good.

Comment: Great. I would have upvoted too, if I could :) A retag has already been done, I see.

Answer (score 1):

I think just creating a synonym should suffice for these. And if we did just merge them, we should just use one of the two spellings. "infoviz" is not a term people are going to think of when they want to use one of these tags.

Comment: You may be right about the `infoviz` tag. We can always get back to that one :)